# Good Design for Initialization of Static Array

Tags: c++, api

I have a question regarding good design in C++.  I have a `class A`, and all objects of this class use an integer array of constant values (they should share the same array, as their values are constant). The array needs to be computed (just once) before any object A.

I thought about having another `class B` which contains the integer array as a static member, an `init()` method which would fill this array according to some formula and a static boolean flag `initialized` (if this variable if true then the `init()` method would do nothing), but I'm not sure this is the best way to solve my design issue.

So my question is, what would be a good design/way to accomplish this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the size of the array compile-time fixed?

Comment: Yes it is. But I would also like to hear about options for the other case, just for the sake of learning. Thanks.

Comment: Well... just initialize it? `std::array<int, N> MyClass::theArray = MyInitializer<false>();` etc.

Comment: To be honest I wasn't aware of `std::array`. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array is constant, use `const`.

Since the array is shared among all instances of the class, use `static`.

In your header file, *declare* it:

```
class A
{
    static const int the_array[10];
}
```

In A's source file, *initialize the one instance*:

```
const int A::the_array[10] = { ... };
```

**Edit from comment...**

Or, if the array is better generated algorithmically, use a constant pointer.  The usage syntax for the array would be the same.

Note that both the array and the pointer are `const`.

*Header:*

```
class A
{
    static const int * const the_array;
}
```

*Source file:*

```
namespace
{
  const int * generate_my_array()
  {
    // Allocate an array, initialize it, return it.
  }
}

const int * const A::the_array = generate_my_array();
```

Comment: But let's say the array's size is 100 and each entry is the n-th fibonacci number (or something which may need some computation/formula, e.g. binomial coefficients) then according to this I would do `array[100] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... };` but is this a clean solution ?